# Number of ways to insert $k\in[n]$ identical elements to two $n$ long lists

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have two lists $a=a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$, $\ \ b=b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{n}$ and we want to determine how many ways there are to insert $k$ identical elements $X$ independently into both lists (i.e. at the beginning, between two elements, or at the end, where we can have consecutive Xs) and $k$ can range from 1 to $n$.

Given $k$, we can model this as choosing $k$ slots with replacement out of the $n+1$ available slots. Since both lists are independent, this should be squared, giving $$\binom{n+k}{n}^{2}$$

Considering any possible $k\in\left[n\right]$, this becomes $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n+k}{n}^{2}$$

Is this analysis correct? If so, what is the best exponential lower bound I can get for the above expression?

Comment: I think it should be $n+k\choose n$ not $n+k-1\choose n$. I don't understand why you are choosing $k-1$ slots when you have $k$ identical elements.

Comment: Oi, you are right of course, thanks.

Comment: I want to point out that $2^{2n}$ is a lower bound for the expression if that is useful to you.

Comment: @Levent Could you provide a reference or a sketch of the derivation for this bound?

Comment: Note that the last summand is ${2n\choose n}^2$ and I used the fact that $2^n\leq{2n\choose n}$.